# Laravel 5.3 - Complex unique rule with formatting check

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

So as part of the project I'm on, we're allowing people to add 'followers' to be notified on updates to a customer's contract. These followers may have multiple e-mail addresses and phone numbers attached to them, using a polymorphic table structure for e-mail addresses (`email_addresses.email`) and phone numbers (`phones.number`). Phone numbers are stored strictly as 10 digits.

I'm trying to add validation rules so that an error is thrown if an e-mail address or phone number is already in use with another follower on this specific record. I would do this at the processing stage when the user's input is scrubbed but I don't know how to add an error message to the error bag and trip the validation as a failure.

Existing rules:

```
'emails' => 'array',
'emails.*' => ['email'],
'phones' => 'array',
// anything with 10 digits, since everything else is being stripped off
'phones.*' => ['string', 'regex:/(?=(?:.*[0-9]){10})/'],
```

I've looked at `Rule::exists()` and found there is nothing to check for the opposite, and I looked at `Rule::unique()` but this doesn't seem to consider this level of complexity. I could potentially grab all the existing e-mails and phone numbers to use with `not_in` but I'm trying not to format the data at this level (the phone number will for instance may never hit a match because it may be submitted formatted but is stored stripped of all formatting characters).

How should I implement this?

Comment: You can use a unique validator with a where clause as outlined in the thread below. Target your polymorphic table.  https://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2015-laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns-for-unique-relations

Comment: The parameter list is unclear about what it means. I don't understand what is meant by `except` or `idColumn`. I also would want to target specifically phone table rows that are related to the customer's contract record since we'd want to be able to put the same phone number for different contracts, just not the current one.